# Audio / Microphone streaming

Tags: audio, microphone, streaming

Is there any way to live stream audio from my Android phone via mobile internet network (broadband), so I could play the stream on VLC player?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an Application [Camtest Audio](http://www.droidbin.com/p1alrjvilfvl31joi1evm1qbilfl3). You can use it for streaming audio/video over the network using WI-FI. I uploaded my app for you in this link:
http://www.droidbin.com/p1alrjvilfvl31joi1evm1qbilfl3

This app is based on an Open Source library called ["Libstreaming"]

Comment: This app can't be installed on Note 5 Android 5.1.1.

Comment: what is the error that you get?